# How to check if a buffer is empty?

Tags: emacs, elisp

How to check if a buffer is empty? Checking if `count-lines` gives 0 is over-killing for this I think.

**UPDATE:** 
Yeah, phils's answer should work. Write it out:

```
(defun buffer-empty-p (&optional buffer)
  (= (buffer-size buffer) 0))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
buffer-size is a built-in function in `C source code'.

(buffer-size &optional BUFFER)

Return the number of characters in the current buffer.
If BUFFER, return the number of characters in that buffer instead.
```